# Error occured processing applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm seeing the error above in my Problems list.
It tells me to look at the Eclipse Error Log, which has the following error.

using Eclipse Mars.1 using STS3.7.1

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.io.EclipsePathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(EclipsePathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ClassResourceFilteringPatternResolver.getResources(BeansConfig.java:1088)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:270)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:453)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: this looks like a bug. I created a ticket here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4258 - would be great if you could go to that ticket and attach a sample project that helps us to reproduce this issue, if possible. That would be great!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I apparently don't have edit acess to that issue. I'm not sure I can create a reproducible test case for you, but I can give you some more details about my project structure. We're using maven submodules, and the applicationContext.xml file is in one of the maven submodules, which is dependent on the other submodules. the error is happening at the <context:component-scan> bean (which you can probably see from the stack trace). One of the packages listed there does not exist in the submodule that the applicationContext.xml lives in - it only appears in another submodule.

Comment: another fact of note - this error didn't appear until after I added <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> to the config file.

Comment: you need to create an account and login to get write access on the ticket (sorry for the inconvenience there). Nevertheless it would be great if you could create a sample project that reproduces the issue somehow (I will try to take a look myself, too).